# Dc characteristics I vs Vce

Tags: transistors

Plase can help me.. why no curve  in negative x-axise (Vce) , why no current in negative vce in npn T why no leakage current  in left side (no curve) as the daiod , where the leakage current hidden

Comment: Perhaps if you took more time to formulate the question, you would get a more positive response. "chrstc", Really?

Comment: Sorry ... im not good in english that best i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curve for Common Emitter with negative Vce is not usually shown because the transistor is not designed to be operated in that mode. With negative Vce the transistor is actually in Common Collector mode, but with Emitter and Collector terminals swapped.

As the junction order is N-P-N it will still work in this mode, but with very low gain because the Collector is normally made larger than the Emitter to optimize gain with positive Vce.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKAV98.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>